Extracting Hurst index from fBM using rescaled range (R/S)
I implemented in Python the rescaled range algorithm to compute the Hurst exponent as follows:
import numpy as np

def hurst(data):                                                                                                                                                                                            
    n = len(data)                                                                                                                                                                                           
    mu = np.mean(data)                                                                                                                                                                                      
    y = data - mu                                                                                                                                                                                           
    z = np.array([y[:i].sum() for i in range(1, n)])                                                                                                                                                        
    r = np.array([z[:i].max() - z[:i].min() for i in range(2, n)])                                                                                                                                          
    s = np.array([np.sqrt(np.mean( (data[: i] - mu) ** 2) ) for i in range(2,n)])                                                                                                                           
    log_rs = np.log(r/s)                                                                                                                                          
    log_time = np.log(range(2,n))
    H, C = np.polyfit(log_time, log_rs, 1)                                                                                                                                                                  
    return H, C, log_time, log_rs

Where log_time and log_rs are the logarithm of the time sequence and of the r/s respectively, while H and C are the coefficients of the line which best fits the scattered plot of log_rs versus log_time. It seems fine to me, but when I compute H for a fractional browninan motion of given Hurst exponent, I expect the above code to give back an H sufficiently close to it, but it always gives back values around 0.7-0.85, regardless of the given Hurst exponent.
My implementation follows
from hurst import random_walk

length = 10000
true_H = 0.3
fbm = random_walk(length, proba=true_H)


H_fbm, C_fbm, log_time_fbm, log_fbm = hurst(fbm)

As already said, instead of having H_fbm any close to true_H I always get H_fbm in the range 0.7-0.85, so there must be something wrong. Any clue?
